# Create a JSON Object that conforms to a particular JSON in python

Tags: python, json

So what i am trying to do is reverse engineer a JSON object in python using a pre-existing file. The file contents are as shown below:

```
[
{
    "id": "PA_vnf",
    "name": "PA",
    "short-name": "PA",
    "description": "A firewall PaloAlto",
    "version": "1.0",
    "connection-point": [
        {
            "type": "VPORT",
            "name": "PA/cp0"
        },
        {
            "type": "VPORT",
            "name": "PA/cp1"
        },
        {
            "type": "VPORT",
            "name": "PA/cp2"
        }
    ],
    "vdu": [
        {
            "id": "pa_vdu",
            "external-interface": [
                {
                    "virtual-interface": {
                        "type": "VIRTIO"
                    },
                    "vnfd-connection-point-ref": "PA/cp0",
                    "name": "eth0"
                },
                {
                    "virtual-interface": {
                        "type": "VIRTIO"
                    },
                    "vnfd-connection-point-ref": "PA/cp1",
                    "name": "eth1"
                },
                {
                    "virtual-interface": {
                        "type": "VIRTIO"
                    },
                    "vnfd-connection-point-ref": "PA/cp2",
                    "name": "eth2"
                }
            ],
            "guest-epa": {
                "cpu-pinning-policy": "ANY"
            },
            "name": "vdu-1",
            "vm-flavor": {
                "storage-gb": 40,
                "memory-mb": 4096,
                "vcpu-count": 4
            },
            "image": "paloAlto_RIP"
        }
    ],
    "service-function-chain": "UNAWARE",
    "meta": "important info"
}
]
```

Just to simplify things, for now i am hardcoding the values of all the keys, the sample code is as shown below:

```
def create_vnf_new ():
  ginfo = nested_dict(5,list)
  ginfo['description'] = 'A firewall PaloAlto'
  ginfo['name'] = 'PA'
  ginfo['id']= 'PA_vnf'
  ginfo['version'] = '1.0'
  ginfo['service-function-chain'] = 'UNAWARE'
  ginfo['short-name'] = 'PA'
  ginfo['vdu']['id'] = 'pa_vdu'
  ginfo['vdu']['name'] = 'vdu-1'
  ginfo['vdu']['image'] = 'paloAlto_RIP'
  ginfo['vdu']['guest-epa']['cpu-pinning-policy'] =  'ANY'
  ginfo['vdu']['external-interface']['virtual-interface']['type'] = 'VIRTIO'
  ginfo['vdu']['external-interface']['vnfd-connection-point-ref'] = "PA/cp0"
  ginfo['vdu']['external-interface']['name'] = 'eth0'
  ginfo['vdu']['vm-flavor']['storage-gb'] = 20
  ginfo['vdu']['vm-flavor']['memory-mb'] = 1024
  ginfo['vdu']['vm-flavor']['vcpu-count'] = 4
  print(json.dumps(ginfo))

def nested_dict(n, type):
  if n == 1:
    return defaultdict(type)
  else:
    return defaultdict(lambda: nested_dict(n-1, type))
```

For which i get the below o/p:

```
{
"short-name": "PA",
"vdu": {
    "name": "vdu-1",
    "image": "paloAlto_RIP",
    "id": "pa_vdu",
    "external-interface": {
        "virtual-interface": {
            "type": "VIRTIO"
        },
        "vnfd-connection-point-ref": "PA/cp0",
        "name": "eth0"
    },
    "guest-epa": {
        "cpu-pinning-policy": "ANY"
    },
    "vm-flavor": {
        "storage-gb": 20,
        "vcpu-count": 4,
        "memory-mb": 1024
    }
},
"description": "A firewall PaloAlto",
"version": "1.0",
"service-function-chain": "UNAWARE",
"id": "PA_vnf",
"name": "PA"
}
```

The above O/P is perfectly fine, but i want certain attributes like "external-interface" to have multiple values which i am not able to do. I tried the append method on the dictionary, but it kept throwing me the error **"'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'append'"**.
Example append that i used: ginfo['vdu']['external-interface']['vnfd-connection-point-ref'].append("value")

I am not sure what is going wrong. Also how do i get the first square brackets in the output, which is missing in my o/p. I know it should be an array but, i am not sure how do i apply array logic on my dictionary object.

If the explanation is not clear enough, please let me know because i am typing this help after about 5 hours of no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Python` expressiveness:

```
ginfo['vdu'] = []
interfaces = []
interfaces.append({'virtual-interface': {'type': 'VIRTIO'}, 
                   'vnfd-connection-point-ref': 'PA/cp0',
                   'name': 'eth0'})
...
...

ginfo['vdu'].append({'id': 'pa_vdu',
                     'external-interface': interfaces})
```

Using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) the reverse engineering of the structure is more clear:

```
>>> pprint(json.loads(json_string))
[{u'connection-point': [{u'name': u'PA/cp0', u'type': u'VPORT'},
                        {u'name': u'PA/cp1', u'type': u'VPORT'},
                        {u'name': u'PA/cp2', u'type': u'VPORT'}],
  u'description': u'A firewall PaloAlto',
  u'id': u'PA_vnf',
  u'meta': u'important info',
  u'name': u'PA',
  u'service-function-chain': u'UNAWARE',
  u'short-name': u'PA',
  u'vdu': [{u'external-interface': [{u'name': u'eth0',
                                     u'virtual-interface': {u'type': u'VIRTIO'},
                                     u'vnfd-connection-point-ref': u'PA/cp0'},
                                    {u'name': u'eth1',
                                     u'virtual-interface': {u'type': u'VIRTIO'},
                                     u'vnfd-connection-point-ref': u'PA/cp1'},
                                    {u'name': u'eth2',
                                     u'virtual-interface': {u'type': u'VIRTIO'},
                                     u'vnfd-connection-point-ref': u'PA/cp2'}],
            u'guest-epa': {u'cpu-pinning-policy': u'ANY'},
            u'id': u'pa_vdu',
            u'image': u'paloAlto_RIP',
            u'name': u'vdu-1',
            u'vm-flavor': {u'memory-mb': 4096,
                           u'storage-gb': 40,
                           u'vcpu-count': 4}}],
  u'version': u'1.0'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't "apply array logic" on a dictionary. If you want an array (ie a list), then use a list. In your original JSON, both `connection_point` and `vdu` are lists of dicts, as is `external-interface` within `vdu`.

If you really still want to build this up line by line, you could do:

```
ginfo['vdu'] = []
ginfo['vdu'].append({})
ginfo['vdu'][0]['id'] = 'pa_vdu'
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @[Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) and @[klashxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1200821/klashxx) i was able to do use both your solutions to build the final code. I have put the code below:

```
import json
import yaml
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

def nested_dict(n, type):
  if n == 1:
    return defaultdict(type)
  else:
    return defaultdict(lambda: nested_dict(n-1, type))

ginfo = nested_dict(5,list)
ginfo = []
ginfo.append({})
ginfo[0]['description'] = 'A firewall PaloAlto'
ginfo[0]['name'] = 'PA'
ginfo[0]['id']= 'PA_vnf'
ginfo[0]['version'] = '1.0'
ginfo[0]['service-function-chain'] = 'UNAWARE'
ginfo[0]['short-name'] = 'PA'
ginfo[0]['vdu'] = []
interfaces = []
interfaces.append({'virtual-interface': {'type': 'VIRTIO'},
                                   'vnfd-connection-point-ref': 'PA/cp0',
                                   'name': 'eth0'})
interfaces.append({'virtual-interface': {'type': 'VIRTIO'},
                                   'vnfd-connection-point-ref': 'PA/cp1',
                                   'name': 'eth1'})
interfaces.append({'virtual-interface': {'type': 'VIRTIO'},
                                   'vnfd-connection-point-ref': 'PA/cp2',
                                   'name': 'eth2'})
ginfo[0]['vdu'].append({'id': 'pa_vdu',
                 'name': 'vdu-1',
         'image': 'paloAlto_RIP',
                 'guest-epa':{'cpu-pinning-policy': 'ANY'},
                 'external-interface': interfaces,
                 'vm-flavor': {'storage-gb': 40,
                 'memory-mb': 4096,
                 'vcpu-count': 4}})
ginfo[0]['connection-point'] = []
cp =[]
cp.append({'type': 'VPORT',
    'name': 'PA/cp0'})
cp.append({'type': 'VPORT',
    'name': 'PA/cp1'})
cp.append({'type': 'VPORT',
    'name': 'PA/cp2'})
ginfo[0]['connection-point'].append({'connection-point': cp})
print(json.dumps(ginfo))

def nested_dict(n, type):
  if n == 1:
    return defaultdict(type)
  else:
    return defaultdict(lambda: nested_dict(n-1, type))
```

and it spewed out the following o/p:

`- 
   "short-name": PA
 vdu: 
  - 
   name: "vdu-1"
   image: paloAlto_RIP
   id: pa_vdu
   "external-interface": 
    - 
   "virtual-interface": 
      type: VIRTIO
     "vnfd-connection-point-ref": "PA/cp0"
     name: eth0
    - 
   "virtual-interface": 
      type: VIRTIO
     "vnfd-connection-point-ref": "PA/cp1"
     name: eth1
    - 
   "virtual-interface": 
      type: VIRTIO
     "vnfd-connection-point-ref": "PA/cp2"
     name: eth2
   "guest-epa": 
    "cpu-pinning-policy": ANY
   "vm-flavor": 
    "storage-gb": 40
    "vcpu-count": 4
    "memory-mb": 4096
 description: "A firewall PaloAlto"
 "connection-point": 
  - 
   "connection-point": 
    - 
   type: VPORT
     name: "PA/cp0"
    - 
   type: VPORT
     name: "PA/cp1"
    - 
   type: VPORT
     name: "PA/cp2"
 version: "1.0"
 "service-function-chain": UNAWARE
 id: PA_vnf
 name: PA`

Which is technically correct. Now the problem is with the double quotes. I don't want double quotes for attributes, however double quotes for values is fine. And the double quotes appear random for the attributes.
Thanks for the help again. I am marking this solved since the original question has been answered.